# laravel eloquent merge 2 queries before executing them?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 2 queries like this:

```
$expiresAt = Carbon::now()->addMinutes(10);
$thumbnails = Cache::remember('entities-thumbnails-'.$entity_id, $expiresAt, function () use ($entity_id) {
    return Images::where(['entity_id' => $entity_id, 'image_style' => 'thumbnail'])
        ->select('path AS thumbnail', 'width As thumbnailWidth', 'height As thumbnailHeight');
});
$largeImages = Cache::remember('entities-largeImages-'.$entity_id, $expiresAt, function () use ($entity_id) {
    return Images::where(['entity_id' => $entity_id, 'image_style' => 'large'])
        ->select('path AS src')
        ->union($thumbnails)
        ->get();
});
```

What I want to do is not execute them seperately but as one query. Overall there will be 4 queries therefore instead of doing 4 I want to do one, is that possible? How does union work exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing whole plain results in PHP variable then let PHP do such filtering would be better in my point of view. As an example

```
$images = Image::where('entity_id', $entity_id)->get();

$thumbnails = Cache::remember('entities-thumbnails-'.$entity_id, $expiresAt, function () use ($images) {
    return $images->filter(function ($image) {
        return $image->image_style === 'thumbnail';
    });
});

$largeImages = Cache::remember('entities-largeImages-'.$entity_id, $expiresAt, function () use ($images) {
    return $images->filter(function ($image) {
        return $image->image_style === 'large';
    });
});
```

You might call `UNION` is literally the same as `JOIN`. But, it does combining results set into one in an operation rather than relate them horizontally. Still, both need to be separated by PHP, as each row recorded are united into one `collection`.

I'm assuming you still need to make aliases for specified columns. Fortunately, Laravel is able to do that out of the box.

```
$thumbnails = Cache::remember('entities-thumbnails-'.$entity_id, $expiresAt, function () use ($images) {
    return $images->filter(function ($image) {
        if ($image->image_style === 'thumbnail') {
            $image->setAttribute('thumbnail', $image->path);  
            $image->setAttribute('thumbnailWidth', $image->width); 
            $image->setAttribute('thumbnailHeight', $image->height);                

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    });
});

$largeImages = Cache::remember('entities-largeImages-'.$entity_id, $expiresAt, function () use ($images) {
    return $images->filter(function ($image) {
        if ($image->image_style === 'large') {
            $image->setAttribute('src', $image->path);  

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: that is a very good explanation. I wasn't aware laravel eloquent has options like this available, I will definitely reuse this for most of my queries. Thanks!